# Rails Active Admin precompile issue for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

When I am compiling the assets it is working properly and it is not giving error for active admin

```
Undefined mixin 'global-reset'.
```

I am stuck in this issue and unable to find any solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in [this issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/810).

Try to add the below to `production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( active_admin.css active_admin/print.css active_admin.js )
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue recently with rails 4:

This can be caused by use of "require_tree ." in application.css. One solution is to move the active_admin stylesheet into vendor/assets/stylesheets.